# prevent caching in browser

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching

I am writing a script which modifies its own contents and I am having a hard time with preventing it from caching itself and NOT showing the updated page...

I have tried everything I can think of...
I added these headers in the PHP code:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); // always modified
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
```

I added these meta tags in the HTML code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

I even added an .htaccess file with this in it:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

...and yet the browser keeps caching it... is there anything else I can do?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the snippet of where you're including the script? How is it modifying itself?

Comment: At the end of the day, the browser may just do whatever the hell it feels like doing - regardless of what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess is fine, even better if you have access to httpd.conf. Either way, that is correct. However, you can also manipulate the browser cache on a per script basis, like so:

```
<?php
 header("Last-Modified: " . <whatever date you want refreshing>));
 header("Expires: " . <whatever date you want refreshing>));
 header("Cache-Control: max-age=<whatever date ..>);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
```

Comment: that is part of what I am doing, as I mentioned in my original post

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear your cache after making changes to the file? I know I wrestled with this before and it was due to a simple factor that I didn't clear out my cache after making the changes. Anyways, you put everything at the top that I would have.

Comment: I am precisely trying to program my script so that I don't have to empty the cache every time, so that it just works without human intervention of that sort...

Answer (score 0):

Most web browsers will cache something based on `Last-Modified`. There are a couple tricks that can always tell the browser to update the file(s) that may be cached:

Using `touch` you can update the timestamp of a file:

```
<?php

$time = time() + 60; // Time Now + One Minute
$file = '/path/to/your/file/';
touch($file, $time);

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) 
           && 
      (strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) == filemtime($file))) {
      // Send Result To Client
      header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($file)).' GMT', 
      true, 304);
      exit;
    }
?>
```

This will update the timestamp on the file +1 minute anytime the page is loaded — it then gets compared to the version the client might have cached locally. You can also use the `$time` variable by itself instead of `filemtime($file)` if you prefer not updating the file timestamp.

Comment: this is an interesting solution I was not aware of, but since there are several routines that write several files, I am looking for a more general and all encompassing solution that can be applied... I wonder if there is...

Comment: The only way you will get the all encompassing solution is to clear the cache on the client side. You could always add the file names you need updated to an array, then `touch` the timestamp so they all get updated at the same time.

Comment: since this method relies on sending the header('Last-Modifie:...') to the client, how is this different/better than sending all the headers that I am already sending, which have an expired date, thus should allegedly force a reload?

Comment: The main difference is this updates the file timestamp, compares it to `HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE` — if equal returns a `304 status` (Not Modified). What you have in your header should be more than enough to force a web-browser to re-validate and get a new version of the page. The only problem is other elements within the page can still remain cached; changing a file timestamp or using a dynamic name implies the file changed from the original that might be in the cache.  What type of files are you needing to ensure aren't cached, are they `.js`, or...?

Comment: I created a CMS script that can modify the CSS file of the script itself as well as the sidebar and other contents of the website... when I change the sidebar for example I don't see the changes until I re-load the page (even the page just loaded after the file has already been created)... the same happens with the CSS file I modified